# Pandas shape mismatch error for keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on a time-distributed CNN based on TensorFlow-Keras. I am confused between the shape of input data required by my model and the actual input data I am providing.

The required input data shape is : `(none,443000,200,160)`
The shape that I have for my data: `(44300,160,1)`
My input data is a dataframe of original shape: `(44300,161)`
I tried using reshape but it doesn't seem to be working.

Below is the model plot that I am using:
[image]

Comment: without knowing anything about the data there is no way we can help.

Comment: What do you mean without knowing about the data? any specific thing you are looking for? I have added some information in the question @QWERTYL

Comment: Well reshape is only meaningful if your data is in a specific format.